# TDD web api that controls hardware

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I have developed a gem that wraps a C api for controlling remote light switches and dimmers. When I developed this gem to do testing I mocked out the underlying C api at compile time with some linking magic and that worked fine i could develop on my desktop without the correct hardware and so on.

Now I want to use this gem in another project to wrap a higher level REST API around it, but I'm struggling with testing.

How should I test my REST API without needing the hardware. Should I in the project include my low level api as a git submodule and muck around with load paths so that I can reuse the low level mock?

Or should i just again mock out the entire API for the new project? I'm at a complete loss here.

Any tips or discussions on this are welcome

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to wrap the same "gem" that wraps the C Api with yet another layer that exposes the REST API. Am I right?
If so, you should either mock the gem or the C API, just as you did with the gem.

"Pure" TDD practitioners usually recommend to isolate the smallest pieces (i.e. mock the gem) in order to drive for SRP (Single Responsibility Principle).

On the other hand, when the layer I'm adding (the REST API in this case) is mainly a wrapper and doesn't have a lot of "business logic" of its own, then personally I'd prefer to write my tests more like integration tests rather than pure unit-tests, so that I test the new layer in its correct context. (I.e. test the Rest API + the gem together, and mock the only the C API)

If this REST API is purely a wrapper, then you can probably reuse your tests, by pushing them to a base class and deriving 2 children: one to test the gem itself, and one to test it through the REST API.
I any case, I always refactor my tests and my code together to remove duplication. Sometimes this leads me to change what I mock and what I don't and improves the overall design, both of the CUT and the tests themselves.

HTH...